# FileConnector with Start Delay

Tags: file, mule, polling, mule-esb, inbound

Hi is there any option to provide start Delay with file:inbound-endpoint?(FileConnector)
(I can see quartz is the alternate solution for this)

```
<flow name="ReadingFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="{file.incoming.files}"
                               connector-ref="DefaultNoStreamingConnector"
                               pollingFrequency="${file.polling.frequency}">

        </file:inbound-endpoint>
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch to fixed frequency. It has such parameter tp delay at first check

```
        <ftp:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" >
        <scheduling-strategy >
            <fixed-frequency startDelay="123" />
        </scheduling-strategy>
    </ftp:listener>
```

Comment: The flow snippet in the question uses ftp:inbound-enpoint, which means it is for Mule 3.x. <ftp:listener> is the connector for Mule 4, which is not compatible with 3.x.

Comment: Sorry. I do no have Mule 3 right now so I cannot verify, but, if I'm not mistaken, it was similar settings for Mule 3.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You could use a [Poll scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/poll-reference) as an alternative to start the flow, but an inbound endpoint can not be used in the middle of a flow because it is a message source (starts a flow), not an operation. You can use the Mule Requester Module to reference an inbound endpoint inside the flow, after the Poll started the flow.

I didn't mention the Quartz endpoint because it has been deprecated for years. The Poll scope replaces it.